# WSO2 Identity Server 3.3.0 change port from 9443 to 443

Tags: wso2

Changing wsO2 port to 443

current URL
https://localhost:9443/devicemgt/

https://localhost:443/devicemgt/

Answer (score 2):

I assume you are referring to WSO2 IoT server 3.3.0.

Since the default port is 9443, you can configure the port offset as -9000 and make it run with port 443. You can open  `<IOTS_HOME>/conf/carbon.xml` and change `<Offset>-9000</Offset>`. Refer [this document](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IOTS330/Changing+the+Default+Ports) for more info.

Also, note that, when we are starting a service in a Linux environment to listen for a port number less than 1024, it will require root permission.

Therefore, the ideal solution may be having a proxy server/ load balancer in front of the WSO2 Server to expose different ports to outside.

Comment: Note that changing the offset will change ALL of the ports used by the product (though not necessarily all ports [in APIM and AM](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ADMIN44x/Changing+the+Default+Ports#main-content)). I'm not sure what will happen with ports < 9000 with this solution